# Error comparing long string output in Python test

Tags: python, string, unit-testing, subprocess, python-unittest

I'm testing a Python script who throws a bunch of bytes (as a string) as the result of his execution.

Firstly, I get the result with:

```
myOutput = subprocess.check_output(["python","../src/myScript.py"])
```

With this, I execute the script and get the output.

Then I compare this result with a really long expected output:

```
expOutput = "382d006e756c6c2c7465737453657450726f706572747953823c75652c6c75614170702c63617074696f6e2c486f6c61206d756e646f203200"
self.assertEqual(myOutput, expOutput, "Script output is not the expected")
```

(It's just a silly test, I'm trying the get things to work).

**Problem:** My test FAILS. Debugging I founded the values are equal.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the code in assertEqual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a stray eol at the end of the output from the called script. Try this:

```
myOutput = myOutput.strip()
self.assertEqual(myOutput, expOutput, "Script output is not the expected")
```